# uploading html files and using python

Tags: python, html

For my forum, I tried uploading a file with html using:

```
<form action="profiles.py" method="post">
<label class="labelOne" for="pics">Change your Profile pic </label>
<input type="file" name="uploadField" />
```

My python function takes that file, creates a file under userprofiles, and writes the data to it:

```
file = open('../data/accounts/userprofiles/'+str(form['name'].value)+'/'+'profilepics', 'w+')
file.write(str(form.getvalue('uploadField')))
file.close()
```

So, If I want `burger.jpg` to be my picture, I upload it, python takes that and creates a file with that name `burger.jpg` using `w+` and then it writes the data to it(which should be the image).

However for some reason, I get no image.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `enctype` of your form to `multipart/form-data`

```
<form action="profiles.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```