# uploading a simple file using php not working

Tags: php

I made a simple upload file and update mysql and it's not doing anything. The page reloads, no file is uploaded and no updates go to mysql.  There might be something I don't understand.

```
<?php 
    include 'datalogin.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) 
    {
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadfile'] ['tmp_name'], "verification/{$_FILES['uploadfile'] ['name']}");
        $insert = "UPDATE members SET id_verification = '". $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']."' WHERE members_id = 1";
        $add_member = mysql_query($insert);     
        header('Location: members.php'); 
        exit();
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >  
    <table width="450" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>Upload file <input type="file" name="uploadfile" value="Browse" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="UPDATE" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

the folder "verification" is CHMOD 777

Comment: Does your server error log tell you anything?

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035116/uploading-html-files-and-using-python

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: do a var dump of `$_FILES` and make sure there is anything in there. echo the return value of `move_uploaded_file` and `$add_member`

Comment: And listen to @DavidNguyen. Add that to your `<form>` tag

Comment: What debugging efforts have you made? Surely you can narrow down the problem with the help of a few `var_dump()` statements.

Comment: with this: enctype="multipart/form-data"  the mysql gets updated, but still no file in the folder.
and mikeW, i don't know how to check the server logs...

Comment: what should I var dump, the file name gets entered in mysql correctly, so I know the var has the info, why is 
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadfile'] ['tmp_name'], "verification/{$_FILES['uploadfile'] ['name']}"); not working...

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not fix your problem, but after you've added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag (as David Nguyen) suggested in his comment (this is required for uploading files in HTML), check your destination string.

```
"verification/{$_FILES['uploadfile'] ['name']"
```

I would highly discourage you from putting arrays inside quotes like that, it will produce unexpected results, as will having a space between array key names. Try this:

```
"verification/" . $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']
```

If you are still having trouble after that, assign a variable to your `move_uploaded_file` function and var_dump the output - chances are permissions aren't set on your destination folder and it's failing because it can't copy the file there:

```
$upload = move_uploaded_file(...
var_dump($upload);
```

Comment: ok, i tried that.. here is my code :

$upload = move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadfile'] ['tmp_name'], "verification/" . $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
var_dump($upload);

when I load the page, I get this 

bool(true) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/www/users/grave6wh/site/test.php:8) in /usr/www/users/grave6wh/site/test.php on line 11

Comment: `bool(true)` means your function succeeded. So your file isn't there?

Comment: no file isn't there... maybe a server issue ? I checked, my folder is chmod 777 .. what else could it be ?