# Read-attribute-missing error while uploading file in Python

Tags: python, file-upload, forms

I am trying to allow a user to upload files to a server from a form, and then display images from my website. The script is Python, which also interfaces to MySQL via cursor.execute commands. I can upload text form fields, but not the file contents, similar to the problem reported at: 
[uploading html files and using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035116/uploading-html-files-and-using-python)

I can upload the selected file name, but not read it; I get a read error.

My code is:

```
#!/home2/snowbear/python/Python-2.7.2/python 
import cgi
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function. 
import smtplib
import shutil
import datetime 
import os
import sys, traceback, re
# Helps troubleshoot python script. 
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
# Import mysql database program. 
import mysql.connector
# Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
try: 
  import msvcrt
  msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
  msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
  message = "No Windows msvcrt to import"
  pass
  print '<form name="PB_Form" action="PB_resubmit.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
...
# Get form values. 
...
  if form.has_key("filePix1") and form["filePix1"].value != "": 
    txtImage1 = form['filePix1'].value
    fileItem1 = form['filePix1']
    if not fileItem1.file:
      print "<br><center>No fileItem1: %s</center>" % fileItem1
    else: 
      data = fileItem1.file.read()
      objFile = open(txtImage1, "w+")
      objFile.write(data)
      objFile.close()
  else:
    newImage1 = False
...
```

I get an error for the line:

```
data = fileItem1.file.read()
```

The error is:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
      args = ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'",)
      message = "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'"
```

Although "fileitem1" is a proper handle to the file entered into the form, since I can get the file name, it however, does not have a "read attribute," as specified in the error message.

I'm using Bluehost for my server. Could the file-read attribute be turned off by the server, or am I missing something, such as another special import for handling files?

Thanks for any suggestions, Walter

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
New note:

The problem was that form['filePix1'] "file" and "filename" attributes were missing; only the "value" attribute existed, and this would only produce the file name, not the file contents.

With much experimenting, I discovered that the browser, Sea Monkey, is causing the problem of missing attributes. When I used Firefox, the "file," "filename," and "value" attributes were normal. I have no idea why Sea Monkey doesn't support file loading attributes.

Walter